# WPF не работает привязка свойства BorderBrush

Tags: wpf, binding, itemscontrol

пытаюсь сделать имитацию выделения Listitem как в ListBox

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="rowInfoImagesControl" ItemsSource="{Binding }">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border 
                    BorderThickness="3"
                    Padding="1" Margin="0,0,0,3"
                    BorderBrush="{Binding selected}">
                <Image x:Name="rowInfoSidebarImagePreview" 
                       Source="{Binding imgsrc}"
                       Tag="{Binding imgpath}"
                       Cursor="Hand"
                       MaxWidth="200" 
                       Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                       MouseLeftButtonUp="RowInfoSidebarImagePreview_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

привязка картинок работает, а BorderBrush не слушается

```
string listSelectedItem = "#FF4C8DFA", notSelectedItem = "#FFFFFFFF";  

class ImgListItem
{
    public string imgpath { get; set; }
    public ImageSource imgsrc { get; set; }
    public string selected { get; set; }
}

ObservableCollection<ImgListItem> imgListItems;

rowInfoImagesControl.ItemsSource = imgListItems;

private void RowInfoSidebarImagePreview_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Image img = sender as Image;

    //1 вариант
    imgListItems.ToList().ForEach(x => x.selected = notSelectedItem);
    imgListItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.imgsrc == img.Source).selected=listSelectedItem;

    //2 вариант
    foreach(var item in imgListItems)
    {
        item.selected = notSelectedItem;
    }

    foreach (var item in imgListItems.Where(x => x.imgsrc == img.Source))
    {
        item.selected = listSelectedItem;
    }
}
```

оба способа не работают.
Почему BorderBrush не привязывается?

Answer (score 0):

решение найдено. помог интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="rowInfoImagesControl" ItemsSource="{Binding }">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <Border 
                    BorderThickness="3"
                    Padding="1" Margin="0,0,0,3"
                BorderBrush="{Binding Selected_}">

                <Image x:Name="rowInfoSidebarImagePreview" 
                       Source="{Binding imgsrc}"
                       Tag="{Binding imgpath}"
                       Cursor="Hand"
                       MaxWidth="200" 
                       Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                       MouseLeftButtonUp="RowInfoSidebarImagePreview_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
        </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

class ImgListItem

```
class ImgListItem: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public string imgpath { get; set; }
    public ImageSource imgsrc { get; set; }
    public Brush selected;
    public string checkvalue;

    public Brush Selected_
    {
        get { return selected; }
        set
        {
            selected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Selected_");
        }
    }

    public string CheckValue_
    {
        get { return checkvalue; }
        set
        {
            checkvalue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CheckValue_");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

обработчик

```
Image img = sender as Image;

imgListItems.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Selected_ = brushnotSelected);
imgListItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.imgsrc == img.Source).Selected_ = brushSelected;
```

выделение работает как в ListBox